# Two divs scroll simultaneously until one reaches bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a tricky request from a client. I have two divs like this:

```
------------------------ - <------|
|               |  1   |          |
|               |  2   |          |
|               |      |          |---- Screen height
|     DIV1      | DIV2 |          |
|               |      |          |
|- - -  -  -  - | -  - | - <------|
|               |  3   |        
|               |  4   |
|               |------|
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
------------------------
```

Both divs have more content than most screen's height so they need to scroll. DIV1 has a lot more content.

My client wants that once the DIV2's content reaches the end, it just stays there (presenting the last content), while the DIV1 keeps scrolling.

For the moment my CSS is like this:

```css
.div1 {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 275px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 275px);
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #282725;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1.6rem 1rem 1rem 1.8rem;
}
```

So, nothing fancy. I tried using `position: fixed` and `overflow:auto` on div2 but they will scroll independently. My client doesn't want that, he wants both divs to scroll together, but div2 to stop once it reaches it's end.

In short, after scrolling for a while, the page would be like this:

```
------------------------ 
|               |   1  |        
|               |   2  |
|               |      |  
|               |      |  
|               |      |  
|               |      |  
|               |      |        
|- - -  -  -  - | -  - | - <------|
|               |      |          |
|               |      |          |---- Screen height
|     DIV1      | DIV2 |          |
|               |      |          |
|               |  3   |          |
|               |  4   |          |
|- - -  -  -  - | -  - | - <------|
------------------------
```

I hope my question is clear. It's not easy to explain what I mean.

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Might be  `position:sticky` what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by applying `position: sticky` and `top: 0` on either one or both columns. Make sure you apply `align-items: flex-start` as well to the container element to disable the default stretch setting.

```css
.header {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    height: 100px;
}

.container {
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-1 {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.col-2 {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col col-1">Integer quis tincidunt magna. Phasellus et diam sit amet elit maximus placerat. Maecenas dignissim rutrum turpis, a tempor neque hendrerit in. Vestibulum vel libero nulla. Suspendisse vitae rhoncus dolor, at laoreet leo. Vestibulum imperdiet libero tellus. Donec dapibus eros neque, id euismod justo viverra vel. Ut porttitor justo eu arcu malesuada faucibus. Morbi nunc justo, venenatis vel sollicitudin quis, imperdiet eget metus. Vestibulum id ex et risus tincidunt blandit non sed augue. Etiam non lacus sit amet erat ullamcorper faucibus dignissim eget est. Cras eget odio in nulla mattis porttitor. Suspendisse euismod a velit et ultricies. Nam molestie molestie rutrum. Integer aliquam tellus justo, sollicitudin placerat metus dapibus vel.</div>
    <div class="col col-2">Morbi scelerisque iaculis lorem, vitae sagittis nulla elementum at. Mauris vestibulum molestie aliquam. Sed ac tincidunt magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed leo diam, fermentum non cursus eu, elementum nec nisl. Etiam maximus mollis nibh ut suscipit. Aliquam scelerisque orci ac libero varius, sit amet auctor odio vulputate. Cras ultricies, nibh non auctor placerat, sem augue auctor ligula, sit amet congue leo sapien id elit. Ut eu sapien a quam maximus faucibus. Nam vehicula cursus nibh et eleifend. Nulla pulvinar felis elementum risus ullamcorper, eget iaculis justo porta. Praesent tristique mi ultrices, sollicitudin magna sit amet, ultricies tortor. Maecenas justo justo, tempus et porta eget, interdum et libero. Sed quis nulla id justo congue lacinia blandit quis metus. Donec tempor dolor sapien, eu ultricies libero bibendum nec. Mauris tortor erat, interdum cursus orci ac, fringilla dictum nulla. Fusce consectetur auctor tortor vel cursus. Maecenas felis nisl, sagittis quis mauris vel, gravida ultrices nulla. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas eget mauris id tortor efficitur laoreet. Nullam pulvinar rhoncus nisi. Nam blandit neque vel cursus feugiat. Morbi condimentum nulla porta est placerat, vitae laoreet augue aliquam. Aliquam et dolor tristique, ultrices augue at, semper enim. Aenean condimentum ipsum sed turpis maximus aliquam. Nullam tincidunt suscipit odio non placerat. Suspendisse nunc orci, rhoncus in nulla condimentum, pretium ultricies quam. Integer quis tincidunt magna. Phasellus et diam sit amet elit maximus placerat. Maecenas dignissim rutrum turpis, a tempor neque hendrerit in. Vestibulum vel libero nulla. Suspendisse vitae rhoncus dolor, at laoreet leo. Vestibulum imperdiet libero tellus. Donec dapibus eros neque, id euismod justo viverra vel. Ut porttitor justo eu arcu malesuada faucibus. Morbi nunc justo, venenatis vel sollicitudin quis, imperdiet eget metus. Vestibulum id ex et risus tincidunt blandit non sed augue. Etiam non lacus sit amet erat ullamcorper faucibus dignissim eget est. Cras eget odio in nulla mattis porttitor. Suspendisse euismod a velit et ultricies. Nam molestie molestie rutrum. Integer aliquam tellus justo, sollicitudin placerat metus dapibus vel.  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! I tried as you suggested but the div scrolls past and doesn't stick at the bottom. I mean, the DIV2 just ends and the page only presents the DIV1. My client wants it to always be presenting the bottom of DIV2, as in the second little sketch I drew.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `position:sticky` but you need to dynamically calculate the value of `top` based on the `div2` content and screen height

```js
document.querySelector('.div2').style.top=(window.innerHeight-document.querySelector('.div2').offsetHeight)+'px';

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
document.querySelector('.div2').style.top=(window.innerHeight-document.querySelector('.div2').offsetHeight)+'px';
})
```

```css
.div1 {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 275px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 275px);
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:22px;
  padding:15px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #282725;
  color:#fff;
  padding: 1.6rem 1rem 1rem 1.8rem;
  flex:1;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis sagittis luctus. Morbi pretium, elit vitae pharetra sollicitudin, sapien nisi bibendum ante, eget eleifend arcu diam eget nisl. Vivamus pretium efficitur diam, eu auctor leo cursus et. Quisque et ipsum et quam varius luctus gravida sed magna. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis sagittis luctus. Morbi pretium, elit vitae pharetra sollicitudin, sapien nisi bibendum ante, eget eleifend arcu diam eget nisl. Vivamus pretium efficitur diam, eu auctor leo cursus et. Quisque et ipsum et quam varius luctus gravida sed magna. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis sagittis luctus. Morbi pretium, elit vitae pharetra sollicitudin, sapien nisi bibendum ante, eget eleifend arcu diam eget nisl. Vivamus pretium efficitur diam, eu auctor leo cursus et. Quisque et ipsum et quam varius luctus gravida sed magna. 
</div>
<div class="div2">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis sagittis luctus. Morbi pretium, elit vitae pharetra sollicitudin, sapien nisi bibendum ante, eget eleifend arcu diam eget nisl. Vivamus pretium efficitur diam, eu auctor leo cursus et. Quisque et ipsum et quam varius luctus gravida sed magna. 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed facilisis sagittis luctus. Morbi pretium, elit vitae pharetra sollicitudin, sapien nisi bibendum ante, eget eleifend arcu diam eget nisl. Vivamus pretium efficitur diam, eu auctor leo cursus et. Quisque et ipsum et quam varius luctus gravida sed magna. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you need this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div1').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#div2').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
 width: 50%;
 height: 70px;
 padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: auto;
 label {
  display:block;
 }
 tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: auto;
            clear: both;
        }
}

#div2 {
 width: 50%;
 height: 70px;
 padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 overflow-x: auto;
 label {
  display:block;
 }
 tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: auto;
            clear: both;
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "div1">
  <table id = "stickyheaders" class = "table table-condensed table-striped small">
    <thead><tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr><tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr><tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr></thead>
  </table>
</div>

<div id = "div2">
  <table id = "tablebody" class = "table table-condensed table-striped small">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
        <td>data6</td>
        <td>data7</td>
        <td>data8</td>
        <td>data9</td>
        <td>data10</td>
      </tr><tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr><tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr><tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
      <th>header5</th>
      <th>header6</th>
      <th>header7</th>
      <th>header8</th>
      <th>header9</th>
      <th>header10</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```